# Problems using ajax to access secure and httponly cookies from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, setcookie, cookie-httponly

My website had no security on cookies and some cookies were set by javascript. For security reasons, I had to add secure and httponly flags and so to adapt my javascript. The only way I found was to use ajax.

I wrote a php script called by javascript thru ajax to set cookies. As I know javascript is monotask and asynchronous tasks are scheduled after the synchronous ones. So I had to modify my code to wait for ajax return before calling next pages. For example (see javascript below), when action is 'RELOAD', if a form tag is found on page, it's submitted, if not, a simple reload is done.

javascript :

```
function setMultiCookie(prm, action) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            setMultiCookieRet(action);
        }
    };
    xhr.open("POST", "setMultiCookies.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("prm="+encodeURIComponent(prm));
}
function setMultiCookieRet(action) {
    switch(action) {
        case 'RELOAD':
            var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
            if (form.length > 0)
                form[0].submit();
            else
                location.reload(true);
        break;
        case 'NONE':
        break;
        default:
            window.open(action,'_self');
    }
}
```

php script setMultiCookies.php :

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
if ($_POST["prm"] == '')
    exit;
$prm = explode('µ', $_POST["prm"]);
foreach ($prm as $parms) {
    list($name, $value) = explode('§', $parms, 2);
    if ($value == "-unSetCookie-")
        setcookie($name, '', 1, "/", "", TRUE, TRUE);
    else
        setcookie($name, $value, 0, "/", "", TRUE, TRUE);
}
?>
```

Example of a call to set cookie var1 to val1 and var2 to val2, to unset val3 and to reload page after that :

```
<span onClick="setMultiCookie('var1§val1µvar2§val2µval3§-unSetCookie-', 'RELOAD');" class="button">
```

It works most of the time but in some cases, especially with form tags, it doesn't. I don't know what happens. I'm sure php script works. I've made some trace displays and I've tested that php setcookie return is set to true. But cookies are not set. I suppose something happens before set is done. I had that problem earlier when I loaded a page in javascript synchronous part.

I would be glad if you know what happens or if you know some way to investigate.

Comment: Adding a PHP endpoint to set arbitrary cookies makes your security worse (CSRF), not better.  You need to learn about web security practices and probably substantially change your architecture to avoid trusting the client.

Comment: @SLaks can a login page that sets cookie be considered a "PHP endpoint to set arbitrary cookies"? Not trolling here, just wondering how much generalization we can put in your sentence.. could help if the OP is a beginner, maybe

Comment: @SLaks Folders are not readable and javascript has no direct access to my cookies. I hope PHP wouldn't allow access if security problems are identified. So where is my security flaw ?

Comment: Any site can make a request to that URL to set a cookie.

Comment: @Kaddath: A login page will validate the login and set a specific cookie; this will set any cookie that an attacker wants.

Comment: @SLaks that's a good answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK. Meanwhile I solved my problem. My example was not a good one, because it works with a span tag. I don't know why, but it doesn't work with button tags. Anyway I replaced button tags by span tags and every thing's allright.

Thank's to SLaks and Kaddath for having a look on my question. My website is an intranet one and needs an AD login to access (written in PHP too).